# Eigenvalues of weighted Laplacian matrix

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The weighted Laplacian matrix element is given by
\begin{align}
L_{ij} \; = \; \Big( \sum_{k} w_{ik} A_{ik}  \Big) \, \delta_{ij} - w_{ij} A_{ij}
\end{align}
$A_{ij}$ is the adjacency matrix element and $w_{ij}$ is the weight. $w_{ij}$ can be **positive** or **negative**. And we consider undirected network, $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$ and $w_{ij} = w_{ji}$.

It is known that for unweighted Laplacian matrix (i.e. $w_{ij} \equiv 1$), its eigenvalues are all non-negative. So if all $w_{ij} < 0$, then the eigenvalues of $L_{ij}$ would be non-positive.

**My question is:**  How to construct a weighted undirected network containing both positive and negative weight such that **all** eigenvalues of $L_{ij}$ would be non-negative.